# Auto Starting & Stopping a YouTube Video with Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, youtube, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I am using Twitter Bootstrap's modal box to pop-up a video `lightbox` when a user clicks on a video thumbnail image (example: http://seniorshomecare.harmonyapp.com/how-we-can-help, use password: shc). If possible, I would like to have the video auto-play when the `lightbox` pops up and auto-stop when the user closes the `lightbox`. There are some similar questions to this, but none of them have helped me out much.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

add `&autoplay=1` to the youtube video url.

http://support.google.com/youtube/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1181821

---

**EDIT:**

You can use the Event show to trigger a function which add the code into the modal

```
$('#myModal').on('show', function () {
  $('div.modal-body').html('<iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/v/itTskyFLSS8&amp;rel=0&amp;autohide=1&amp;showinfo=0&amp;autoplay=1" width="500" height="281" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>'); 
});
```

**Demo :** http://jsfiddle.net/baptme/WrrM3/

The solution is not complete, you will have to remove the iframe when closing the modal.

Comment: That auto-plays the video when you load the page. I don't want the video to start playing until you click on the preview image and the lightbox appears. What do you think?

Comment: @Andrew good point, you can use the event `Show` like describe in http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals and insert the video link with `autoplay=1` using jQuery in the opened modal.

Comment: @Andrew, I would recommend using the `shown` event, as it will account for any transitions that may occur while showing the modal

Comment: @jackwanders i thought about using `shown` instead of `show` but because the video takes a lot more time to load than the css transition to finish, it doesn't really matter.

Comment: Thanks guys, that works! I guess I use "hide" to remove the html and therefore stop it?

Comment: @baptme Just accepted it. Sorry about that! Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 4):

This will remove the iFrame when the modal is closed:

```
$('#myModal').on('hide', function () {
$('div.modal-body').html('&nbsp;');  
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WrrM3/82/

Answer (score 2):

The above answers work nicely **if you have only one modal** on your page.  If you have several, your video will be loaded into all of your other modals, and begin playing concurrently in some browsers.

To fix that issue, be more specific with the javascript that inserts and removes the video by adding `#myModal` before `div.modal-body`, as follows:

```
$('#myModal').on('show', function () {
  $('#myModal div.modal-body').html('<iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/v/itTskyFLSS8&amp;rel=0&amp;autohide=1&amp;showinfo=0&amp;autoplay=1" width="500" height="281" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>'); 
});

$('#myModal').on('hide', function () {
  $('#myModal div.modal-body').html('&nbsp;');  
});
```